# YQL and FLickr query not understood in the console

Tags: php, rest, yql, flickr

So I am trying to use YQL to access the flickr api but I have been having some issues. From reading the YQL info, it seemed like I could use any flickr query in YQL but for some reason I cannot use flickr.people.getPublicPhotos call to access all pictures from a certain person. When I try any such query it isn't recognized. Is this possible? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing the flickr API and the YQL tables for the flickr API.

The flickr API is a bunch of methods to call on flickr (like the `flickr.people.getPublicPhotos` one you mentioned). The flickr tables are on the right for http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console under flickr. If you click "Community tables" then there are a few more flickr tables.